# new to Spring frame work getting this error : Could not autowire field:

Tags: spring, jdbc, autowired, spring-jdbc

I having problem new to spring technology

created a controller 
service interface
service implimentation
xml file
where we have jdbc information

Please do the needful

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.jdbc.service.TaskDetailService com.controller.MainController.taskDetailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.jdbc.service.TaskDetailService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My controller

```
@Autowired
    TaskDetailService taskDetailService; //this inject's your bean here.

/**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveTaskDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTaskDetails(
            @ModelAttribute("taskDetails") TaskDetails taskDetails, Model model) {
        logger.info("TaskDetails save the information");



        System.out.println("------------->" + taskDetails.getTaskDuration());

        taskDetails.setLoginId(1);
        taskDetails.setPriorityId(1);
        taskDetailService.saveTaskDetails(taskDetails);

        return "sucess";
    }
```

my service and my impl

```
public interface TaskDetailService {

        public void saveTaskDetails(TaskDetails taskDetails);

}
```

---

```
private TaskDetailDao taskDetailDao;

public void setTaskDetailDao(TaskDetailDao taskDetailDao) {
    this.taskDetailDao = taskDetailDao;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveTaskDetails(TaskDetails taskDetails) {
    taskDetailDao.saveTaskDetails(taskDetails);
}
```

now my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="xyz" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleNativeJdbcExtractor"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor">
        <property name="nativeConnectionNecessaryForNativeCallableStatements"
            value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="nativeAwareJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="simpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.school.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <!--<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> <property name ="transactionTemplate" 
            > <ref bean ="transactionTemplate" /> </property> -->
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="nativeAwareJdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskDetailDao" class="com.jdbc.dao.TaskDetailDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="nativeAwareJdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="taskDetailService" class="com.jdbc.service.TaskDetailServiceImpl">
        <property name="taskDetailDao" ref="taskDetailDao"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.xyz" />



</beans:beans>
```

my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!--   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  -->


</web-app>
```

could any one help me out please

Comment: Please show us how you define the Controller in the Servlet context

Comment: added the main xml file

Comment: Are you sure that the class TaskDetailServiceImpl implements TaskDetailService ?

Comment: yes it is done properly

Comment: Please show us the web.xml

Comment: added web.xml file...

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the xml configuration which contains taskDetailService bean definition into main xml configuration file with

```
<import resource="classpath:my.xml" />
```

Comment: You dont need to do that because taskDetailService is in the root context that is visible by default in the servlet context (not the other way round though)

Comment: It is somehow invisible (due to configuration), thus spring throw BeanCreationException. If the bean definition for taskDetailService is visible and TaskDetailServiceImpl implements TaskDetailService, then there is no reason for this exception. Something is misconfigured here.

Answer (score 0):

in controller class you are autowiring TaskDetailService . But you did not create bean configuration for TaskDetailService to autowire. Add one of stereotype annotation(@Component, @Service, @Controller) to TaskDetailService like

```
@Component
public interface TaskDetailService {

    public void saveTaskDetails(TaskDetails taskDetails);

}
```

or create xml configuration in applicationcontext.xml like

```
  <bean id="taskDetailService" class="/package/TaskDetailService" />
```

If it do not solve, controll that linked applicationContext.xml into web.xml.